# Word meaning "ad hoc unofficial police force"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've completely forgotten the word I'm looking for, but it basically means an "ad hoc unofficial police force" that is formed by citizens to enforce the law when the state can't or won't. Closest words I can think of are paramilitary and lynch mob, but it's neither of those. Can anyone jog my memory?

Comment: Vigilate group?

Comment: A *militia* is a military force that is raised from the civil population to supplement a regular army.

Comment: Typo, @BoldBen:  *vigilante*.

Comment: @TRomano I like to think of them as Vigil-lattes

Comment: @Spagirl: Vigil-lattes keep you up?

Comment: Yes *vigilante* was what I was looking for I think.  Thanks.

Comment: ***posse***....

Comment: Auxiliary police force comes to mind, but it’s not usually used with an ad-hoc connotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like "vigilante" was what I was looking for.

Comment: You're sure it wasn't vigilante?

Comment: Or vigiluncle ?

Comment: My apologies for my typo last month and thanks to Tromano for pointing it out, it should be "vigilante" as @oerkelens says.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what spin you want to put on it.

You could use "lynch mob," but that has a negative connotation.  What's more, that's not people being unofficially deputized but people taking the law into their own hands.  The official legal term for doing that in legal theory or doctrine is "[self-help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-help_(law))," which in Latin is "*pro se*."

"[Vigilante group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigilante)" comes to mind as a term that is connotationally neutral, the term "vigilante mob" being less so.

A "posse" is a group that can either be officially or unofficially assembled, at times unofficially assembled by a sheriff or lawperson that lacks the authority to officially deputize.

Other terms that come to mind are "*coram non judice*," "*pro se* *ad hoc* justice," "*ex proprio motu*," "*ex curia*, " and "extrajudicial punishment."

I guess I'm stuck on what you mean by "unofficial."  Do you mean unofficially deputized by

Answer (score -1):

The word "**militia**" would seem to be the best answer to the question, but"**civilian**" can be used as a single word adjective to describe any peace keeping "*force*".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/civilian